# Convert underscore to PascalCase, ie UpperCamelCase

Tags: shell-script

If I have a string that looks like this:

```
"this_is_the_string"
```

Inside a bash script, I would like to convert it to PascalCase, ie UpperCamelCase to look like this:

```
"ThisIsTheString"
```

I found that converting to lowerCamelCase can be done like this:

```
"this_is_the_string" | sed -r 's/([a-z]+)_([a-z])([a-z]+)/\1\U\2\L\3/'
```

Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with regexes to modify this.

Comment: (1) This doesn’t really matter, as far as this question (and the answers presented so far) are concerned, but, FYI, `\U\2` inserts the found text from the second group, converted to ALL CAPS.  Compare to `\u\2`, which inserts the text in Sentence case, with only the first character capitalized.  (2) All of the examples given below will translate “this_is_a_string” to “ThisIsAString” — which is what you asked for, but is slightly hard to read.  You might want to revise your requirements for the special case of a one-letter word (substring).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Do you have only one such string per line?  And is it always the first (or the _only_) text on the line?  If you have a string that’s not at the beginning of the line, the below answers will convert it to lowerCamelCase.  To fix, take Janis’s answer and change `(^|_)` to `(\<|_)`.

Comment: inverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795479/awk-sed-script-to-convert-a-file-from-camelcase-to-underscores

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
$ echo "this_is_the_string" | sed -r 's/(^|_)([a-z])/\U\2/g'            
ThisIsTheString
```

Substitute pattern
`(^|_)` at the start of the string or after an underscore - first group
`([a-z])` single lower case letter - second group
by
`\U\2` uppercasing second group
`g` globally.

Comment: Note: `\U` is a GNU extension to POSIX.

Comment: Just a note, you should capture numbers too `sed -r 's/(^|[-_ ]+)([0-9a-z])/\U\2/g'`.
So strings like *"this_is_2nd_string"* work too.

Comment: How can I achieve this with non-GNU sed?

Comment: not working well on mac 
~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
~$ 
~$  echo "this_is_the_string" | sed -r 's/(^|_)([a-z])/\U\2/g' 
UthisUisUtheUstring

Answer (score 15):

Since you're using `bash`, if you stored your string in a variable you could also do it shell-only:

```
uscore="this_is_the_string_to_be_converted"
arr=(${uscore//_/ })
printf %s "${arr[@]^}"
ThisIsTheStringToBeConverted
```

`${uscore//_/ }` replaces all `_` with space, `(....)` splits the string into an array, `${arr[@]^}` converts the first letter of each element to upper case and then `printf %s ..` prints all elements one after another.
You can store the camel-cased string into another variable:

```
printf -v ccase %s "${arr[@]^}"
```

and use/reuse it later, e.g.:

```
printf %s\\n $ccase
ThisIsTheStringToBeConverted
```

Or, with `zsh`:

```
uscore="this_is_the_string_to_be_converted"
arr=(${(s:_:)uscore})
printf %s "${(C)arr}"
ThisIsTheStringToBeConverted
```

`(${(s:_:)uscore})` splits the string on `_` into an array, `(C)` capitalizes the first letter of each element and `printf %s ...` prints all elements one after another..
To store it in another variable you could use `(j::)` to joins the elements:

```
ccase=${(j::)${(C)arr}}
```

and use/reuse it later:

```
printf %s\\n $ccase
ThisIsTheStringToBeConverted
```

Comment: This seems a great solution, but unfortunately doesn't work on mac whose bash version is stuck at 3.2.57 because of license issues.

Comment: @wlnirvana, AFAIK macOS has always come with `zsh` (even used to be `/bin/sh` there and it's the default interactive shell in newer versions I'm told) where it's just `${(j[])${(s[_]C)string}}` or `${${(C)string}//_}`

Answer (score 13):

Here's a Perl way:

```
$ echo "this_is_the_string" | perl -pe 's/(^|_)./uc($&)/ge;s/_//g'
ThisIsTheString
```

It can deal with strings of arbitrary length:

```
$ echo "here_is_another_larger_string_with_more_parts" | 
    perl -pe 's/(^|_)./uc($&)/ge;s/_//g'
HereIsAnotherLargerStringWithMoreParts
```

It will match any character (`.`) that comes after either the start of the string or an underscore (`(^|_)`) and replace it with the upper case version of itself (`uc($&)`). The `$&` is a special variable that contains whatever was just matched. The `e` at the end of `s///ge` allows the use of expressions (the `uc()` function in this case) within the substitution and the `g` makes it replace *all* occurrences in the line. The second substitution removes the underscores.

Comment: Speaking of perl, there's also a perl module [String::CamelCase](http://search.cpan.org/~hio/String-CamelCase-0.02/lib/String/CamelCase.pm) that "camelizes" underscored text.

Comment: @don_crissti ooh, sounds perfect for this. Thanks.

Comment: Shorter Perl: `perl -pe 's/(^|_)([a-z])/uc($2)/ge'`

Comment: Or: `perl -pe's/_*([^_]*)/\u$1/g'`

Comment: and how dow we assign the output to another variable? To call it without echo? (sorry a newbie)

Comment: @RahulGandhi please see [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16024)

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary to represent the *entire* string in a regular expression match -- sed has the `/g` modifier that allows you to walk over multiple matches and replace each of them:

```
echo "this_is_the_string" | sed 's/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g;s/^\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g'
```

The first regex is `_\([a-z]\)` -- each letter after underscore; the second one matches the first letter in a string.

Answer (score 6):

I only put in this answer because it is shorter and simpler than any other so far.

```
sed -re "s~(^|_)(.)~\U\2~g"
```

It says: upcase, the character following a `_` or the start. Non letters will not be changed, as they have no case.

Comment: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." – Albert Einstein.  This is not equivalent to the other answers; your answer will convert "FOO_BAR" to "FOOBAR", while the other answers will leave it alone.

Comment: @scott Ah yes, I did not think of that.

Comment: @Scott Isn't that the desired behavior? I guess that ideally, it should become `FooBar` but the underscore should be removed as per instructions. As I understand the instructions anyway.

Comment: @terdon: “Isn’t that the desired behavior?”  (1) I don’t know.  And I don’t believe that we _can_ know what the OP wants unless he tells us; the question is insufficiently explicit.  (2) I occasionally chastise people for making unwarranted assumptions about the potential input from the example(s) presented.  But, considering that the question is about case conversion, I believe it’s valid to extrapolate (from the fact that the example is all lower case) to the assumption that the OP wants to manipulate only lower case strings.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) I think it’s somewhat clear that the spirit of the question is to transform a string so that word breaks indicated by underscores (`_`) are instead indicated by case transitions.  Given that, “FOO_BAR” → “FOOBAR” is clearly wrong (as it discards the word break information), although “FOO_BAR” → “FooBar” may be correct.  (4) Similarly, a mapping that causes collisions seems to be contrary to the spirit of the question.  For example, I believe that an answer that converts “DO_SPORTS” and “DOS_PORTS” to the same target is wrong.

Comment: (Cont’d again) …  (5) In the spirit of not causing collisions, it seems to me that “foo_bar” and “FOO_BAR” should not map to the same thing, so therefore I object to “FOO_BAR” → “FooBar”.  (6) I think the bigger issue is namespaces.  I haven’t programmed in Pascal since Blaise was alive, but in C/C++, by convention, identifiers that are primarily in lower case (to include snake_case and CamelCase) are generally the domain of the compiler, while identifiers in upper case are the domain of the pre-processor.  So that’s why I think that the OP didn’t want ALL_CAPS identifiers to be considered.

Answer (score 4):

In perl:

```
$ echo 'alert_beer_core_hemp' | perl -pe 's/(?:\b|_)(\p{Ll})/\u$1/g'
AlertBeerCoreHemp
```

This is also i18n-able:

```
$ echo 'алерт_беер_коре_хемп' | perl -CIO -pe 's/(?:\b|_)(\p{Ll})/\u$1/g'
АлертБеерКореХемп
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
echo "this_is_the_string" | sed -r 's/(\<|_)([[:alnum:]])/\U\2/g'
```

and got this result:

```
ThisIsTheString
```

Answer (score 0):

My choice is:

```
echo "this_is-the_string-2.0" |  perl -pe 's/(?:^|[^a-z])([a-z0-9])/\u$1/g'
```

Which results in:

```
ThisIsTheString20
```

Comment: Or `perl -pe 's/([a-z0-9]+)|./\u$1/g'`

Comment: nice, but I find it a bit cryptic in fact