# using date in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, date

I have a problem with the use of the date command in a shell script; this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find . -type f -mtime +10 ); 
do
    echo "$i"
    echo "ligne dans la boucle";
    #il faut verifier si il a ete créer un samedi ou pas;
    jour=`ls -lrt $i| awk '{print $7}'`;
    mois=`ls -lrt $i| awk '{print $6}'`;
    annee=`ls -lrt $i| awk '{print $8}'`;
    requette="date -d '$mois $jour $annee' +'%a %u %A'";
    echo $requette;
    test=$($requette);
    echo $test;
    echo " ";
done
```

So the output is like this:

```
date: extra operand ‘2015'’
```

but when I use the command directly on the shell it works :/

```
requette="date -d 'Feb 28 2015' +'%a %u %A'"
```

If anyone can help me that would be great!

Comment: There are too many things wrong here... 1) [Don't loop over `find`'s output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) 2) Don't parse the output of `ls` (and as a general rule, don't run a command N times if you need to extract N strings from its output) 3) Learn how to [assign the output of a command to a variable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16024) - as right now you definitely don't know how to do it. 4) What is the point of ending each line with a semicolon ? 5) _"si il a ete créer"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find regular files that are more than 10 days old and that have been last modified on a Saturday (in the timezone of the user running the script), with GNU tools (and you seem to be on a GNU system as you're using a GNU-specific option to `date` and the GNU shell), you can do:

```
find . -type f -mtime +10 -printf '%Tu%p\0' |
  sed -zn 's/^6//p' |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

While GNU eventually added (yet a different) `stat` command in the early 2000s to query file metadata in a more scriptable fashion that with `ls`, most of its functionality was already in GNU `find` long before that and with a much better interface than GNU `stat`'s.

Most other `stat` implementations can give you the modification time in any format, GNU `stat` can't (the reason why you end up resorting to a combination of `ls` and GNU `date` in your question I suppose) but GNU `find` can (with GNU `date`, you could also use `date -r "$file" +%u`).

Above `%T<format-letter>` is the modification time using the specified `strftime` format. `%Tu` is the day of the week as a number from 1 (Monday) to 7. That's better in scripts than using `%a`/`%A` that are locale dependant.

We're printing that number followed by the file path, NUL delimited to be able to handle file names with newline characters, and piping to `sed` to select the records that start with `6` (and remove that 6 for them). The NULs are then translated to newline on output.

`-z` was added to GNU `sed` in 2012. If your `sed` is older, you can change the above to:

```
find . -type f -mtime +10 -printf '%Tu%p\0' |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
  sed -n 's/^6//p' |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Generally, [you don't want to loop over the output of `find` like you do in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/22565). If you wanted to loop over the files found by `find` in `bash`, you'd rather do:

```
 while IFS=/ read -d '' -ru3 day file; do
   case $day in
     (6) printf '"%s" was last modified on a Saturday\n' "$file";;
   esac
 done 3< <(find . -type f -mtime +10 -printf '%Tu/%p\0')
```

In `zsh`, you could also do:

```
zmodload zsh/stat # for zsh's stat builtin
last_modified_on_a_saturday() {
  local -A stat
  stat -LF %u -H stat -- ${1-$REPLY} &&
    ((stat[mtime] == 6))
}
for file in **/*(ND.m+10+last_modified_on_a_saturday); do
   do-something with $file
done
```

Comment: arg !! an answer from Stéphane, I just have to humbly delete mine ... :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can considerably simplify matters by using the `stat` command in place of `ls`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(find . -type f -mtime +10 ); 
do
   echo "$i"
   echo "ligne dans la boucle";
   #il faut verifier si il a ete créer un samedi ou pas;

   #///////////////////////
   #jour=`ls -lrt $i| awk '{print $7}'`;
   #mois=`ls -lrt $i| awk '{print $6}'`;
   #annee=`ls -lrt $i| awk '{print $8}'`;
   #requette="date -d '$mois $jour $annee' +'%a %u %A'";
   #//////////////////////////////

   # get the month, year, and day from stat-ing the file
   mois_jour_annee=`stat -c '%y' "$i" | cut -d' ' -f1`

   # and then...
   requette="date -d '${mois_jour_annee}' +'%a %u %A'";

   echo "$requette";
   test=$(eval "$requette");
   echo "$test";
   echo " ";
done
```

Comment: See my comment on the question. Since this is a copy-paste of OPs code (except for the `ls` part which was replaced by `stat`) it has the same pitfalls and problems as the OP's code.