# How to store the output of calculation to variable using bash script

Tags: shell-script, bc

I want to do a simple coding by storing the product of calculation using command `bc` into variable.

```
answer="$varnameX % $num1" | bc
echo "the result is $answer"
```

it did not show the product of calculation once i run the command

```
the answer is
```

Comment: See also: [How can I assign the output of a command  to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16024/80216)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `bc`, then:

```
answer=$(echo "$varnameX % $num1" | bc)
echo "the result is $answer"
```

Or:

```
answer=$(expr $varnameX % $num1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer=`expr $varnameX % $num1`
```