# How to capture all std outputs

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal

Suppose I have a program called mktemp which creates a random tmp directory in `/tmp` and also produces a string output of the directory address

```
Input[0]: mktemp
Output[0]: /tmp/tmp.MkrKAscwwk
```

How can I redirect the output of mktemp so that I can change my directory to that I just created? Meaning I Don't have to do `cd /tmp/tmp.MkrKAscwwk`.

Comment: Or better ... [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable)

Comment: `cd "$(mktemp  | tail -n1 | cut -d: -f2)"`