# modify output of command to input as a variable to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I am trying to modify the output of a command , store it to a variable and pass it to another command in a single line. I tried using xargs, but didnt work well.

hre is the first command

```
echo "DIS NAMELIST(CLUSNL.TO.QMWC.SSL) NAMES"|runmqsc -w 10 -x QMWC |grep NAMES |grep -v DIS
```

output is

```
NAMES(CLDEV.ISCC.74                                   ,CLPRF.ISCC.74                                   ,CLSYS.ISCC.74)
```

Modified ouput is to remove CLDEV.ISCC.74  and store the modified output to a variable

```
NAMES(CLPRF.ISCC.74                                   ,CLSYS.ISCC.74)
```

new command to be issued

```
echo "ALTER NAMELIST(CLUSNL.TO.QMWC.SSL) $VARIABLE"|runmqsc -w 10 -x QMWC |grep NAMES |grep -v DIS
```

Here is what I could get to get the desired output, but trying to figure out how to store this to a variable and pass it to new command

```
`echo "DIS NAMELIST(CLUSNL.TO.QMWC.SSL) NAMES"|runmqsc -w 10 -x QMWC |grep NAMES |grep -v DIS|sed 's/CLDEV.ISCC.74`                                   ,//'
```

Comment: So, your question is [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable) - or something else?

Answer (score 0):

To store the result without `CLDEV.ISCC.74...,` into variable `VARIABLE`, use:

```
VARIABLE=$(echo "DIS NAMELIST(CLUSNL.TO.QMWC.SSL) NAMES"|runmqsc -w 10 -x QMWC |grep NAMES |grep -v DIS | sed 's/CLDEV\.ISCC\.74[[:space:]]*,//')
```

Your new command should work as expected.

Comment: I am trying to feed the variable into a command on the same line like below
echo "DIS NAMELIST(CLUSNL.TO.QMWC.SSL) NAMES"|runmqsc -w 10 -x QMWC |grep NAMES |grep -v DIS | sed 's/CLDEV\.ISCC\.74[[:space:]]*,//' | echo "ALTER NMELIST((CLUSNL.TO.QMWC.SSL) NAMES"|runmqsc

Comment: You could replace `$VARIABLE` of your new command with the content of `$(...)` (if that's what you mean), but I think the code gets unreadable and messy.