# Python output to a shell variable

Tags: bash

I have a .py code that gives me a number which I want to save to some shell variable because I need to use a if/fi loop on that variable. How can I do that?
My a.py gives me 1.0 and my condition is sth like: 
if 
 $x <= 1.5
do sth

I need the .py output to go to $x.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable) - however, be aware that `bash` itself can really only perform integer arithmetic

Comment: For comparing fractional numbers, you'll need a different tool, like bc: `x=$(python code.py); if (( $(echo "$x <= 1.5" | bc) )); then ...`

Comment: I tried: x=$(python code.py) ; echo $x. I get error message: command not found.

Comment: Are you certain? I just tried the following and it works fine for me: `x=$(python3 -c 'import sys ; print(sys.version[0:3])'); echo $x`

Comment: @RAJENDRATHAPA The command substitution (the `$(...)` bit) in that comment should contain the shell code necessary to invoke your Python script. So use the command in there that you would normally use to run the Python script.