# Why the following bash snippet is not working?

Tags: linux, bash

This question is related to Bash. The following is working in terminal:

```bsh
url="http://user:pw@example.com:80/"
echo $url | sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/'
```

Terminal output: `example.com`

How to fix the following?

```bsh
domain=$($url | sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/') # not working
echo $domain
```

Comment: you forgot `echo` in `domain=$(echo "$url" | ...)`; and please do not duplicate your question of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/624145/72456

Comment: @ αғsнιη THX. That works: domain=$(echo "$url" | sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/'); echo $domain

Comment: @ roaima THX. I checked the linked source before submitting my question. A I didnt successfull tu adapt the solution from follow, for my question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left side of the pipe has to be a valid shell command that
produces output to stdout. In bash you can also use `<<<` like that:

```
domain=$(sed -e 's/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/' <<< "$url")
```

Comment: @ Arkadiusz Drabczyk Thats working fine. THX