# How to run a command using another command output as part of its text in terminal?

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

If *`command1`* is:

```sh
curl -k -v -u user:password https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/tag -H Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json 2>&1 | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}'
```

which output, for example, the following `Docker-Content-Digest`:

```
> sha256:12345...
```

knowing that running each command separately works, how to inject *`command1`* output as part of *`command2`* text as:

```sh
curl -k -v -u user:password -X DELETE https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/(command1 output)
```

I am just trying to run one command only!

---

**Update:**

When I combine them together using the double quote as following:

```sh
curl -k -v -u user:password -X DELETE https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/"$(curl -k -v -u user:password https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/tag -H Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json 2>&1 | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}')"
```

I get the following output and *`command2`* never executed:

```
> * Illegal characters found in URL
> * Closing connection -1 
> * curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

---

**Update 2**

when I use single quote, I get the following output:

```
> < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
< Server: nginx/1.21.3 
< Date: Tue, 28 Sep
> 2021 13:46:50 GMT 
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 <
> Content-Length: 19 
< Connection: keep-alive <
> Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0 <
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < 404 page not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable)

Comment: `echo "thisis$(echo "test")"` or better using `printf`: `printf 'thisis%s' "$(echo "test")"`

Comment: you want to use command substitution https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

echo thisis$(command1)

Comment: @rAlen see update please. substitution didn't work

Comment: @pLumo using variables is not as injecting the output in command text. PLease check my update

Comment: try putting "$(curl -k -v -u user:password https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/tag -H Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json 2>&1 | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}')" put double quotes before and after $(), also what is the error you are getting, are you getting an error or wrong output that isn't an error

Comment: You are getting JSON back from that `curl` command. Consider showing that document. It's easier to parse JSON using `jq` than with `grep` and `awk`.

Comment: @McLan Can you give more detail about how substitution "didn't work"?

Comment: @rAlen still not working . please check question update

Comment: @DonHolgo Please check question update (the command I tried and the output)

Comment: @McLan your initial question and especially formatting was quite misleading and also very unclear what you wanted to achieve. Also I suggest reading [how to ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: Thank you @polemon for your your kind explanation. I just tried to ask a question with simplest syntax possible.

Comment: @McLan what do you get if you manually paste the output to the end of the URL, is curl working then, is the URL valid then. This is probably an issue with special characters like $ or ! inside URL which bash expands/substitutes to something else and then URL becomes unusable. If you have special characters like that in URL you need to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean:

```sh
echo "thisis $(echo 'test')"
```

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you can try a bunch of things:

1. You can substitute each part of the command pipe and see where the error is. So far, you didn't do any actual debugging, as far as I can see.
2. You could simply assign the output of the first command into a variable:

```sh
CMD1=$(curl -k -v -u user:password https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/tag -H Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json 2>&1 | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}')
curl -k -v -u user:password -X DELETE https://example.com/v2/image/manifests/"$CMD1"
```

Obviously I can't debug any of that, as I don't have access to the actual result set of either command - that's for you to try and debug further.

I any event, the `$(…)` syntax is called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), and it's explained in the man pages of shells that support it (which is pretty much every single modern one).