# declare one variable modified input to another variable and create a file with the 2nd variable name

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

My bash script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$i" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'

    # -- problem in this area -- 
    filenames="$i"
    #declare -a $filenames=$i
    # -- upto this line ---

    cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.cpp "$filenames".cpp
done
```

With the help of this code `echo "$i" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'` 
If number of inputs are `A B.cpp C D.cpp`, it will turn to `A B C D`

I need `A B C D` to go into `for-loop` and become `A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp D.cpp`

**My problem:** I'm not being able do that. *(Failed)*

1. tried to implement latest `echo $i` which is `A B C D` 
   `cp -v ~/Desktop/library/template.cpp "$i".cpp` 
   didn't work
2. tried another way. declaring the variable `$i` to the variable `$filenames` 
   couldn't implement it correctly

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: You appear to be asking [How can I assign the output of a command to a shell variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-shell-variable) however there's a much simpler way to remove the suffix from the contents of variable `$i` using the shell's own parameter expansion `${i%.*}`

Comment: There's no need to delete your post; it can serve as a useful entry-point / signpost for future readers with similar problems. Thanks!